# Equiprobable allocation of balls into bins

Tags: probability, combinatorics, sampling

Is there a strategy of placing $m$ balls into $n$ bins of varying capacities so that no allocation is more probable than any other? For example, suppose we have two balls to be placed in two bins, each big enough to hold the two balls. There are three possibilities: one ball in each bin, and both balls in either one of the bins. What sampling procedure will generate any of these possibilities equally?

Comment: Please clarify: Are you ok with a one-step sampling process, which simply generates the numbers of balls in the bins, like $(2,0)$ or $(1,1)$ or $(0,2)$ in your example? Or are you asking for a sequential sampling process that places balls one by one, and in the end the different allocations should be equiprobable?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Yes, I am okay with a one-step sampling process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decide the number of balls $a_1$ in the first bin, count the number of possible arrangements in the other $n-1$ bins if $a_1=0$, or $a_1=1$, and so on.  Then pick a random number with proportional probabilities,to decide the value of $a_1$.  Then go onto the next bin.